# @MessageDriven doesn't work in JBoss AS 5

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

The code as given below throws a `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException`. I think that it might be some kind of problem with JBoss AS 5.

```
package web;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import org.jboss.jms.server.connectionfactory.ConnectionFactory;

public class MyMDBClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        QueueConnection cnn = null;
        QueueSender sender = null;
        QueueSession session = null;
        InitialContext ctx;
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",
                    "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
                    "org.jboss.naming");
            props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "127.0.0.1:1099");

            ctx = new InitialContext(props);
            Queue queue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("jms/txt");
            QueueConnectionFactory factory = (QueueConnectionFactory)new ConnectionFactory();
            cnn = factory.createQueueConnection();
            session = cnn.createQueueSession(false, QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage("Hello World");
            sender = session.createSender(queue);
            sender.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Message sent successfully to remote queue.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and mdb:

```
package web;

import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

@MessageDriven(mappedName="jms/txt",
        activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(
                propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"
        ) })
public class FirstMDB implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {


    }

}
```

---

should i create that on server personally?i think it created automaticly by this nottation??is not true?

Comment: >should i create that on server personally?i think it created automaticly by this nottation??is not true? - Are you trying to ask whether a JMS queue is created automatically by defining a bean that listens to it? If so, the answer is no. You have to define the actual queue yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `destinationName` is missing which indicates for which topic/queue the MDB will listen the messages.

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/txt", activationConfig =  {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationName", propertyValue = "jms/txt")
    }   
)
```

Also *verify* whether the particular queue is created on the server in admin console, lookup is being failed.

Answer (score 0):

The `nameNotFoundException` indicates that the name you're trying to lookup in JNDI doesn't exists. So, either you don't have a queue defined at all, or you're using the wrong name.

Can you show the xml file where you define the queue?

Furthermore, as Nayan also indicates, the `destination` property is missing. This is required. Additionally, your usage of the `mappedName` annotation attribute is completely wrong here and should be omitted. Additionally, as the MDB is using the default container managed transactions the `acknowledgeMode` is being ignored and thus does not need to be specified.

The code should look like this:

```java
@MessageDriven( 
    activationConfig = {        
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"), 
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "/queue/yourQueue") 
    }
)
public class FirstMDB implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {    

    }    
}
```

As for your client, typically you also need to lookup the `ConnectionFactory` from remote JNDI and don't forgot to close the connection obtained from it. For JBoss AS 5.x and 6.x the JNDI name of this factory is simply `/ConnectionFactory`.

As an idiomatic example of sending a JMS message:

```java
ConnectionFactory factory = getFactoryFromJNDI();
Connection connection = null;
try {
    try {
        connection = factory.createConnection();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);            
        Destination destination = getDestinationFromJNDI();

        MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(destination);    
        Message message = session.createTextMessage("Hello World");

        sender.send(message);        
    }
    finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
catch (JMSException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Where `getFactoryFromJNDI()` and `getDestinationFromJNDI()` simply wrap the JNDI lookup code.